# initializing 2Darray of Objects

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, object

hello everyone this weird thing happened in this code

```
public CoreManager[][] mng = new CoreManager[5][];


void Start()
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
        {
            mng[y] = new CoreManager[5];
            mng[x][y] = new CoreManager();
            mng[x][y].actual_words = new string[5];   
            mng[x][y].actual_words[y] = "test "+y;
            Debug.Log(mng[x][y].actual_words[y]); //this code work fine and show the elements in the log
        }
    }
    Debug.Log(mng[0][0].actual_words[0]);//this code gives an error 
}
```

this is the debug log from unity engine:
[image: this is the debug log from unity engine]

as u can see it gives me an error if i tried to print
the value of the array after initializing it although  it will print it with no problem if it was inside the for loop while initializing

i spent 7 hours yesterday on this  :D

Comment: I highly recommend following [this Microsoft debugger tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2019).

Comment: It's not really clear what your expectation is with this code as you seem to be using `x` and `y` to mean many different things. An odd point is that you're declaring `mng` to contain 5 arrays, and then you're only using 3 of the slots. You're then using `y` to mean both the position in the nested array, and a position in the `actual_words` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're tying yourself up in knots a little there. The first concern is that you mix up the indexers on your `mng` item i.e. `mng[x]` then you use `mng[y]`. You're also redeclaring the item in the second loop that you don't need to.

Give this code a try and use as your template. It should do the trick:

```
void Start ( )
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
    {
        mng[x] = new CoreManager[5];
        for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
        {
            var c = new CoreManager();
            c.actual_words = new string[5];
            for (var z = 0; z < c.actual_words.Length; z++)
                c.actual_words[z] = $"Manager [{x}][{y}] Actual Word [{z}]";

            mng[x][y] = c;
        }
    }
    Debug.Log (mng[0][0].actual_words[0]);//this code gives an error 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has multiple issues:

First of all, `mng` is initialized with a count of **5** elements and the for loops iterate **only 3** of them.

Then, the very first instruction setting something inside `mng` is inside the second loop, using the `y` iterator, and all sbusequent instructions use the `x` iterator in its place.

The following is a possible solution:

```
public const int Length0 = 5;
public const int Length1 = 5;
public CoreManager[][] mng = new CoreManager[Length0][];

void Start()
{
    for (int x = 0; x < Length0; x++)
    {
        var mng_x = new CoreManager[Length1];
        mng[x] = mng_x;

        for (int y = 0; y < Length1; y++)
        {
            var mng_x_y = new CoreManager();
            mng_x[y] = mng_x_y;

            mng_x_y.actual_words = new string[5];   
            mng_x_y.actual_words[y] = "test " + y;
            Debug.Log(mng_x_y.actual_words[y]); //this code work fine and show the elements in the log
        }
    }
    Debug.Log(mng[0][0].actual_words[0]);//this code gives an error 
}
```

Note that local variables `mng_x` and `mng_x_y` help avoiding use of wrong indices throughout the instructions following their declarations; furthermore, they avoid fetching the same array elements more times than needed.